# C# Sql Server Obtener imagen

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola tengo un problema para poder obtener una imagen desde Sql Server, la imagen yo no la guardo es de un software de terceros, cuando trato de obtener la imagen me sale el siguiente error.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((Byte[])reader["Company_Logo"])) {
            var myImage = new Bitmap(stream);
 }
```

Este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que trae el campo de imagen en sql (solo una parte porque esta muy largo)

> 0x151C2F00020000000D000E0014002100FFFFFFFF4269746D617020496D616765005061696E742E506963747572650001050000020000000700000050427275736800000000000000000080360000424D763600000000000076000000280000002001000060000000010004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000008000008080000000008000800080000080800080808000C0C0C000F

Alguna idea :(

Comment: Que tipo de dato tiene el campo Company_Logo en la tabla ? es un image o quizas un varbinary

Comment: Es la columna es Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias primero ver de recuperar el byte array usando

```
var image = (byte[])reader["Company_Logo"];
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\..\imagenLogo.jpg", image);
```

[File.WriteAllBytes(String, Byte[]) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.8)

Asi validas en el archivo fisico que se genera en la ruta se escribe la imagen, si lo hace entonces sabes que es una `byte[]` lo que se persiste, pudiendo cambiar a

```
var logo = (byte[])reader["Company_Logo"];

Image imageLogo;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(logo)){
   imageLogo = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

o quizas usar

```
var logo = (byte[])reader["Company_Logo"];

Bitmap bitmap;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(logo))
{
    using (Image imageFromStream = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFromStream);
    }
}
```

si necesitas que sea `bitmap`

Comment: Me sirvió lo segundo (como Bitmap), muchas gracias :)